# WebSocket Not Connected

Tags: javascript, websocket, promise, atmosphere

I was working on building an atmosphere.js web-socket PUSH based notification API. I wanted to promisify the application. I've written the following code as shown below:

```
function PushConnection() {

'use strict';
 this.socket = atmosphere;
 this.request = new atmosphere.AtmosphereRequest();
 this.request.url = 'wss://echo.websocket.org';
 this.request.contentType = 'application/json';
 this.request.transport= 'websocket';
 this.request.reconnectInterval= 5000;
 this.request.timeout= 60000;
 this.subSocket = this.socket.subscribe(this.request);
}

PushConnection.prototype.subscribe = function(data) {
    'use strict';
var self = this;
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       self.request.onMessage = function(response) {
          if (response.responseBody === '') {
              resolve('No Result.');
          } else {
              var responseBody = response.responseBody;
              console.log(responseBody);
              resolve(responseBody);
          }
       };

       self.request.onError = function(response) {
          reject(response.responseBody);
       };

      self.subSocket.push(data);
   });
   return promise;
};
```

But when I open in the browser the application throws the following error: "Websocket Not Connected". Please find the stack trace below:

```
log @   atmosphere.min.js:1
error   @   atmosphere.min.js:1
X   @   atmosphere.min.js:1
u   @   atmosphere.min.js:1
AtmosphereRequest.push  @   atmosphere.min.js:1
(anonymous function)    @   pushPromise.js:32
PushConnection.subscribe    @   pushPromise.js:17
```

Thanks in advance.